# Flutter update a map value inside a list

Tags: flutter

Hello everyone i am trying to update a map value inside of a list if the value already exists then it should just update the quantity. The problem is that the code only works for the first entry and does not work for the rest of them.

here is my code.

for (var map in items) {
print(countItem.indexOf(_productIndex));

```
    if (map['\'id\''] == '\'$_productIndex\'') {
      var toRemove = countItem.indexOf(_productIndex);
      items.removeAt(toRemove);
      items.add({
        '\'totalQuantity\'': count,
        '\'type\'': '\'unit\'',
        '\'id\'': '\'$_productIndex\'',
        '\'price\'': count * int.parse(_productPrice),
        '\'name\'': '\'$_productName\'',
      });
    } else {
      items.add({
        '\'totalQuantity\'': count,
        '\'type\'': '\'unit\'',
        '\'id\'': '\'$_productIndex\'',
        '\'price\'': int.parse(_productPrice),
        '\'name\'': '\'$_productName\'',
      });
    }

    break;
  }
```

Comment: Cannot you use a map instead of list? See `Map.putIfAbsent` method

Comment: @pskink I have a list of map items [ {'id':1, 'quantity': 2},{'id':2 'quantity': 2}]. I want to be able to loop through it to check if id already exist then update the quantity by one or add a new map if does not exists whenever a button is clicked. The problem is that it only works the first time and does not work again.

Comment: i asked why don't you use a map instead of list

Comment: Can you show me a sample of what you mean if there is way to do it.

Comment: `putIfAbsent` returns your item, so all you need is to increment your quantity

Answer (score 0):

Your using `indexOf` for the wrong variable. Change it from _productIndex to map.

```
for (var map in items) { 
   print(countItem.indexOf(map));
   ...
```